# Jquery not woking on mac

Tags: jquery

Jquery alert is not displayed on mac

```
$(document).window.onLoad(function(){
   alert('jquery loaded successfully');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

There is syntax error in your code. Use it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert('jquery loaded successfully');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like this

```
$(document).window.onLoad
```

If you wanna to alert on load in jquery

Try like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('jquery loaded successfully');
});
```